# What do we do when a user edits their own post while not logged in or logged in as a different user?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

Triggered by these two suggested edits:

https://serverfault.com/suggested-edits/7537
https://serverfault.com/suggested-edits/7538

Do we *reject* and suggest that the user logs in properly or *approve* and hope that it is actually the person who originally asked the question?

Comment: I personally would never approve an edit that contains "lol", no matter who wrote it, and I would definitely never approve on that contained stuff we normally edit out, such as "hi" and "thank you".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would reject both, with a message to tell him to log on to his original account if he's the owner of the question.

The first one should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The latter I would reject - the question is old, has (accepted) answers and there is no evidence that the edit is by the OP. I'm not sure if the anonymous user would get an custom reject message but I might add one advising them to ask their own question.

The former ... it's a train wreck. The edit partially answers the original question badly and then re asks the original question poorly too. I'd be tempted to reject it and ask the OP to provide an answer as to how they got lighty working and then to ask another question if they still have one.

The OP of the question really doesn't appear to understand how the site works and more importantly needs education rather than a Q&A site.

ooh looking more closely the OP asked the question 3 hours ago but the edit says

> Hi, finally managed to get lighty to work with everything I want. Took
>   many days

so there is something weird going on here.

Answer (score 1):

Not in regards to the two examples (handling them has been covered well by pauska and Iain).

If the edit is obviously by the OP, I generally approve it and try to merge the accounts if the edit was not by "anonymous".

If there's reasonably doubt that the edit was not by the OP, then I generally reject with a message saying to login first.